# Initialization of global structure in C (GCC 4.5.2)

Tags: c, struct, initialization, arm

I am writing a code in C for STM32 using CodeSourcery GCC 4.5.2 for ARM. I am facing problems in initialization of a global structure. The code is given below.

In struct.h

```
typedef struct
{
  int foo;
  ...
  int bar;
} mystruct;

extern mystruct example;
```

In struct.c

```
mystruct example = {100,200 ..., 1000};
```

In Main.c

```
#include "struct.h"

int temp;
temp = example.foo;
```

The code compiles without any problems. But while debugging, I find that the structure has been initialized with all garbage values!! The value of temp should be 100 but it always turns out to be a garbage value. I am using eclipse + openOCD + GDB hardware debugging at the PC and Olimex JTAG on the hardware end.

Is this a problem of the compiler? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Note: In struct.c i have included struct.h

Comment: So, this is at file scope? int temp; temp = example.foo; You say it compiles... which is interesting, because the compiler should reject that. It is a bug in your compiler that this even compiled, unless some bizarre extension is at play here. You can only initialize variables at file scope to compile time constants: int temp = 0x14;

Comment: By "compiles" do you mean "compiles and links"?  You'll need the object code from both `Main.c` and `struct.c`.

Comment: Wait, what?  It's perfectly legal to declare a variable and later assign a value to it.

Comment: Can you try assigning example.foo = 100; in struct.c? and then read it in your main. If it works fine then you might have some alignment / padding issue (although all types are ints and it appears less likely but making sure is important).

Comment: its illegal to set value of a _variable_ to a global variable. Global variables can only be initialized with constants @AdamLiss

Comment: @AdamLiss: "file scope", "file scope".  We are talking about globals here.

Comment: @Aniket I guess you meant assigning local variable to global. I thought it was just placed as an example on file scope. It has to be inside main or some other function

Comment: @DietrichEpp i guess you make a valid point. It was a mistake to down vote with an assumption. It should have been clarified in the question and it is valuable info that you added. Can you please edit/elaborate your point a bit perhaps so i could change my vote?

Comment: The assignment of the `struct` object occurs at runtime as oppose to compile time, where as global variables are initialized during compile time. If the compiler does not catch the error, it will initialize the global variable with garbage value. Bugfree compiler _will_ catch this error

Comment: There seems be no problem with the code as such and the OP doesn't give more precisions, voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment of the struct object occurs at runtime as oppose to compile time, where as global variables are initialized during compile time. If the compiler does not catch the error, it will initialize the global variable with garbage value. Bugfree compiler will catch this error

Comment: This answers is incomprehensible.

Comment: Sorry for the previous one, upvoting

Comment: thanks @icepack I wouldn't have known what the _real_ question was.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved. I am using a custom linker script for the STM32 which has added support for C++. I commented out the below lines in the linker file and magically the global structures started to initialize with the values provided!

```
__exidx_start = .;
.ARM.exidx : 
{
    *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
} >flash
__exidx_end = .;

.preinit_array : {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
} >flash

.init_array : {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
} >flash

.fini_array : {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
} >flash
```

I don't know what the above lines exactly do (except that they are required for C++ constructors to work). I am still wondering even though none of the source files in the project have any C++ code, what was this particular code in the linker file doing such that my global structures were being initialized with garbage values?

Answer (score 0):

It's fine just make sure that you are providing both `.c` files during compilation and making
only executable .
I tried with my gcc 4.5.2

main file :

```
cat gst.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include "gst.h"
int main()
{
int temp;
temp = example.foo;
printf("%d\n",temp);
return 0;
}
```

another file c file

```
cat ggst.c
#include"gst.h"
mystruct example = {100,200};
```

gst.h file :

```
typedef struct
{
  int foo;
  int bar;
} mystruct;

extern mystruct example;
```

`gcc -Wall -Werror gst.c ggst.c -o g`

`./g`

output is 100

Comment: I don't think there is any problem

Comment: how is your answer different from mine?

Comment: @Aniket : I havn't seen your answer actually,I just did that and pasted here .. sorry

Comment: I tried with -Wall -Werror options @Aniket

Comment: He is on an embedded arm platform (and you probably tested on desktop linux or something) so padding / alignment and many other possible things could cause the difference.